# Xamarin Android App with multidex and stack trace

Tags: android, xamarin.android, decompiling, android-multidex

I created Xamarin Android app with multidex.  I use hockeyapp for crash monitoring.  This is my stack trace:

```
MySpace.MyPage.c004d6fcaf7de57319f01e8b57c149cb4()<dcaea0e8fc154c4c8d3fb16637016fa2>:0
MySpace.MyPage.c2b8486191bd85edf32b8f6498dd867b8.c7e99716f7684490efa5fb61d0ddf4f79()<dcaea0e8fc154c4c8d3fb16637016fa2>:0
MySpace.MyPage.cd793501a5adc9c3bd442847ebe56b06f.c7e99716f7684490efa5fb61d0ddf4f79()<dcaea0e8fc154c4c8d3fb16637016fa2>:0

....
```

If I understand correctly - dcaea0e8fc154c4c8d3fb16637016fa2 is md5 hash my method(in MyPage). How can I find my method full name?

Md5 to string it is not possible. It remains only to study and decompiling my dex file([with dex2jar and jd-gui](https://przemekraciborski.eu/2016/09/30/multidex-in-xamarin/)).

Any other other(simpler) ideas?

Comment: hockeyapp won't encrypt your stacktrace string, could you please disable the encryption in your project?

Comment: Does it multidex option? But I can not disable this option otherwise the application will not work (many libraries)